# Implementing bulk-messaging from Salesforce to/from Twilio, hitting Salesforce API limits

Tags: sms, salesforce, twilio, apex, callouts

I am building an integration between Salesforce and Twilio that sends/receives SMS using TwilioForce REST API.  The main issue is getting around the 10-call API limit from Salesforce, as well as the prohibition on HTTP call outs from a trigger.

I am basing the design on Dan Appleman's Asynchronous Request processes, but in either Batch mode or RequestAsync(), ASync(), Sync(), repeat... I'm still hitting the limits.

I'd like to know how other developers have done this successfully; the integrations have been there for a while, but the examples are few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending unique messages for each record that has been updated? If not, then why not send one message to multiple recipients to save on your API limits?

Unfortunately, if you do actually need to send more than 10 unique messages there is no way to send messages in bulk with the Twilio API, you could instead write a simple application that runs on Heroku or some other application platform that you can call out to that will handle the SMS functionality for you.

Comment: I don't see a way to send to multiple even with a single message; To, From, and Message, per callout, is the only method I came across.

Comment: Unfortunately looking the problem over again, you are correct, my experience with the twilio API is a bit dated and I recalled the ability to send group messages, but I was incorrect. At this point my only workable solution would be to push the data to an external service that can send the messages for you without the limitations imposed by SFDC.

Comment: @DuncanStewart - I am hitting the same issue of more than 10 messages and I am trying to see how to call the process asynchronously. Are you saying that even with Asynch this is an issue?

Comment: @DuncanStewart - Are you using TwiML to reply to the text? If yes then it has a 10 message limit. So in that case use their rest API.

Comment: @Ditty - Replies are a different matter altogether; I have a process that works fine in Sandbox/Dev orgs, but running into an issue involving server certificates in Production.  But no, I'm not using TwiML - I'm calling Twilio Rest API from Salesforce, and it's Salesforce's limits on Callouts during a single transaction that were the problem.  But now it's working :D

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now using the following structure (I apologize for the formatting - it's mostly pseudocode):

ASyncRequest object:
 AsyncType (picklist: 'SMS to Twilio' is it for now),
 Params (long text area: comma-separated list of Ids)

Message object:
  To (phone), From (phone), Message (text), Sent (boolean), smsId (string), Error (text)

Message trigger: passes trigger details to CreateAsyncRequests() method.

CreateAsyncRequests:  evaluate each new/updated Message__c; if Sent == false for any messages, we create an AsyncRequest, type=SMS to Twilio, Params += ',' + message.Id.

// Create a list to be inserted after all the Messages have been processed
    List requests = new List();

Once we reach 5 message.Ids in a single AsyncRequest.Params list, add it to requests. 
If all the messages have been processed and there's a request with < 5 Ids in Params, add it to requests as well.

```
If requests.size() > 0 {
  insert requests;
  AsyncProcessor.StartBatch();
}
```

AsyncProcessor implements .Batchable and .AllowsCallouts, and queries ASyncRequest__c for any requests that need to be processed, which in this case will be our Messages list.

The execute() method takes the list of ASyncRequests, splits each Params value into its component Message Ids, and then queries the Message object for those particular Messages.

StartBatch() calls execute() with 1 record at a time, so that each execute() process will still contain fewer than the maximum 10 callouts.

Each Message is processed in a try/catch block that calls SendMessage(), sets Message.smsId = Twilio.smsId and sets Message.Sent = true.

If no smsId is returned, then the message was not sent, and I set a boolean bSidIsNull = true indicating that (at least) one message was not sent.

** If any message failed, no smsIds are returned EVEN FOR MESSAGES THAT WERE SUCCESSFUL **

After each batch of messages is processed, I check bSidIsNull; if true, then I go back over the list of messages and put any that do not have an smsId into a map indexed by the Twilio number I'm trying to send them From.

Since I limited each ASyncRequest to 5 messages, I still have the use of a callout to retrieve all of the messages sent from that Twilio.From number for the current date, using

```
client.getAccount().getMessages('From' => fromNumber, 'DateSent' => currentDate)
```

Then I can update the Message.smsIds for all of the messages that were successful, and add an error message to Message.Error_on_Send__c for any that failed.